# Setting Stackdriver Logging log level for Docker's gcplogs log driver

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, docker, google-compute-engine

Docker supported the `--log-driver=gcplogs` option to log a Google Compute Engine instance to the Stackdriver Logging service (aka Google Cloud Logging).  However, all log entries in the Logs Viewer page at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs have no severity level - the entire log line gets placed in a `data` field like this:

```
{
  metadata: {
    projectId: "my-project"
    serviceName: "custom.googleapis.com"
    labels: {
      custom.googleapis.com/secondary_key: "secondary_key"
      custom.googleapis.com/primary_key: "primary_key"
    }
    timestamp: "2016-05-10T00:07:28.700617425Z"
    projectNumber: "12345"
  }
  insertId: "2016-05-09|17:07:28.706161-07|1.2.3.4|1234"
  log: "gcplogs-docker-driver"
  structPayload: {
    container: {
      imageName: "us.gcr.io/my-image/name"
      created: "2016-05-09T15:09:15.15158629Z"
      name: "/my-container"
      id: "7b6f9fa1d7517e6a3004b8fa7e52asdfddd8e63d02e43afb3942681a56f4e"
      imageId: "sha256:20605d3fdc700asdfa8b08a4aed1f745a0b5d9a8f08ae0db2f90af0bd093"
    }
    data: "2016-05-10 00:07:28,700 DEBUG [my-file:191][uWSGIWorker1Core0] Some log message here"
    instance: {
      zone: "us-east1-b"
      name: "broker-1"
      id: "12345"
    }
  }
}
```

I know that stdout and stderr of a Container get logged by Docker, but how can I configure things (Docker, Compute Engine, Stackdriver Logging) to parse my messages to have a log level?

Comment: Have you tried adding "severity" to the "level" which is recognized by the fluentd cloud logging plugin that should parse it and set the severity of the log entry accordingly. FYI there is an open issue to make this configurable https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-google-cloud/issues/4